# How to replace column value with other table column value?

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, sql-update

I have 2 tables and want to replace the column value with value from other column value. I want to use `REPLACE` function within `Begin..End` statement. Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
Declare  
  l_id    Varchar2(20);     
  l_name  Varchar2(20);  
  l2_name Varchar2(20);  
Begin   
  Select t1.id,t1.name, t2.name 
    into l_id,l_name,l2_name 
    From t t1 join ta2 t2 
      on t1.id = t2.id ;   

  Select Replace(Replace(t2.name,'Name', t1.name), 'Id', t1.id);  
End
```

[image: Table and result]

Comment: Sounds like you need UPDATE statement instead of SELECT. Unless I am missing something, please consider learning basic SQL.

Comment: @gnudiff Thanks for your comment. I'm learning SQL scripts. Thing is that I don't wanna update it in my table. I just want to replace those values and print it for test purpose and use for other purpose.

Comment: have you ever tried the demo with `common-table-expression` including `replace()` function provided below ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just issue a `select` with the expression:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, replace(replace(t1.details, 'Name', t2.name), 'Id', t2.id)
into l_id, l_name, l2_name 
from t t1 join
     ta2 t2 
     on t1.id = t2.id ;
```

Note:  The query is bringing back as many rows as it generates, which might result in an error.  Your query is not clear on what you really want to do.

If you want an `update`, perhaps you intend just to reset the name in one of the tables:

```
update t1
     set name = (select t2.name from ta2 where t2.id = ta.id)
     where exists (select 1 from ta2 where t2.id = ta.id);
```

Comment: @user10990065 . . . The `select` query seems to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't want to update the result table instead I just want to replace the column values say place holders with the values from other table. I need to loop table something like this but stuck. Begin
for i in (Select t1.id, t1.name, t2.name  into l_id,l_name,l2_name from t t1 join ta2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id ; ) loop 
dbms_output.put_line('name:'|| i.l_name); 
dbms_output.put_line('name2:'|| i.l2_name); 
end loop; End;  \ Though this doesn't work as I get more common records matching the condition.

Comment: the select statement works really great. Thanks alot. Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `PL/SQL` blocks, but it could be managed by a single `update` statement :

```
update table1 t
   set details = (
  with cte as (
    select *
      from table2 
  )
  select replace(replace(t.details,'Name',cte.name),'Id',cte.ID)
    from cte 
   where cte.DOB = t.DOB
 );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f946656fe20d7dd5570cdfb9b219f917)</kbd>